# Why are Japanese manga not coloured unlike Korean Manhwa?

Tags: manga-production, mangaka

In general, most Japanese manga are not colored, except for title page or centre color pages, rarely.
However, most Korean manhwa manage to colour their works while maintaining a good standard of art, also in their weekly deadlines.

Comment: [related post: why do manwha more oftenly have colored pages then manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7417/1458) & [Why are manga black and white?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4286/1458) if not duplicate